# Swift - reference a member in an array with a variable

Tags: arrays, swift, variables, multidimensional-array

I've got a multidimensional array and am trying to reference one of the member names using a variable ("ageVariable" in the snippet below), in the same way as the element is referenced using the variable "ageRangeSelected".

This is my code:

```
let time = Journey[ageRangeSelected].ageVariable
```

ageVariable can be either "day", "evening" or "night".

Is this even possible? As written I get the following error:

"Value of type 'Journey' has no member 'ageVariable'"

Here's the code that defines the array - I want to be able to access either member "day", "evening" or "night" using a variable.

```
struct Journey: Identifiable, Equatable {
    let id: Int
    let age: String
    let day: Int
    let evening: Int
    let night: Int
    let drivers: Int
}

func createJourneyMale() -> (Array<Journey>) {
    let journeyMale1720 = Journey(id: 1, age: "17-20", day: 4521, evening: 1243, night: 946, drivers: 440)
    let journeyMale2129 = Journey(id: 2, age: "21-29", day: 5302, evening: 1254, night: 737, drivers: 1877)
    let journeyMale3039 = Journey(id: 3, age: "30-39", day: 5874, evening: 1166, night: 572, drivers: 3015)
    let journeyMale4049 = Journey(id: 4, age: "40-49", day: 6358, evening: 1298, night: 616, drivers: 3282)
    let journeyMale5059 = Journey(id: 5, age: "50-59", day: 6710, evening: 1155, night: 594, drivers: 2877)
    let journeyMale6069 = Journey(id: 6, age: "60-69", day: 6534, evening: 814, night: 418, drivers: 2388)
    let journeyMale70 = Journey(id: 7, age: "70+", day: 5643, evening: 495, night: 242, drivers: 2156)
    let journeyMale = [journeyMale1720, journeyMale2129, journeyMale3039, journeyMale4049, journeyMale5059, journeyMale6069, journeyMale70]
    return (journeyMale)
}

let Journey = createJourneyMale()
```

Comment: Show the Journey array declaration. If it's two dimensional you need to give the selectedIndex for second dimension.

Comment: It's unclear. Multidimensional array? I'm not seeing it in your example. What's Journey ? Also, naming your array without a "s" (or plural form to be correct) and starting with an uppercase is misleading on its type and value. Do you have a concrete example?

Comment: What is Journey? Can you post the code where you declare Journey?

Comment: Apologies - please see updated code above. I basically want to be able to access either member day, evening or night according to the value of a variable. I can see how it's possible to access a specific element but not a specific member using a variable.

Answer (score 0):

First of all there is no multidimensional array. It's a simple one-dimensional array.

Second of all name a variable representing an array always in plural form and name variables always with starting lowercase letter.

```
let journeys = createJourneyMale()
```

Third of all the argument of `return` and the return value are not functions, the parentheses are misleading and confusing.

```
func createJourneyMale() -> Array<Journey> {

...

return journeyMale
```

---

The only way to use a variable to access multiple different properties is a `keyPath`

```
let ageVariable = \Journey.evening

let time = journeys[ageRangeSelected][keyPath: ageVariable]
```

Comment: Perfect - thank you, Vadian. I'm new to all this so your feedback is really helpful.